# Cloud Function parse JSON in form Data

Tags: google-cloud-functions

So I am having a problem trying to get JSON to parse that is posted in a form field.  I have logged the data and see the JSON, but when I try to parse I get invalid token errors.  Is there something different to do?

```
var myjson = req.body.key;
console.log('MYJSON: '+myjson);
var myjson = JSON.parse(req.body.key);
console.log('EVENT: '+myjson.eventType);
```

The last log shows undefined.  I am not sure what I need to do different, I have tried to use urlencoded of the body, but that gives another error.  Just wondering what needs to be done differently. I have read the docs and have not found a solution for this.  The myjson log looks like this:

```
{"eventType":"ALERT_TRIGGER", "title":"ALERT TRIGGER: Port Errors", "text": "Alert: Inbound Port Errors for MA300XNSN5K16C - port-channel8 · *** VPC to Blade Server Switch BC1000E1R16C4C_A1 this hour is 9174 errors and Outbound Port Errors this hour is 0 errors"}
```

Thanks

Comment: You assign req.body.key to myjson, but then you parse(req.body) instead?

Comment: sorry that was a type of the many variations I have tried.  I updated with the actual code being used now.

Comment: Doing `console.log('MYJSON: '+myjson)` can be misleading. Try doing `console.log('MYJSON: ', myjson)`, or just `console.log(myjson)`, so that the type of the value affects its appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script (replace `myjson` with yours, ofc). This might show you where the problem is.

In this example, there's a badly inserted quote in "world".

```js
const myjson = '{"hello":"beautiful worl"d"}';
let currentPart = '';
let lastValidPart = '';
console.log(myjson.length);
for (let i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
  currentPart = myjson.substr(0, i);
  try {
    JSON.parse(currentPart + '"}');
    lastValidPart = currentPart;
  } catch (error) {}
}
console.log(lastValidPart);
```

Comment: I am getting the unexpected token at position 232.  Not sure why though, it works from another webhook that sends application/json but the one I am trying to get to work from Solarwinds sends as form data, can not find out what it is sending to make it fail.  If I stringify before I parse, then it appears to parse, but none of the objects are accessible, they show as undefined. i.e. `myjson.eventType comes back as undefined`

Comment: @Robert check if there are any escaped quotes there. Maybe you're getting `undefined` because you end up with strings instead of objects.

Comment: no quotes in the data, can not find what at pos 232 would cause the unexpected token.

Comment: So I am testing with another object that returns this JSON
`{"eventType":"ALERT_TRIGGER", "title":"ALERT TRIGGER: Port Errors", "text": "Alert: Inbound Port Errors for Pulse SSL VPN - New York (MA003VPN01) - ext0 this hour is 0 errors and Outbound Port Errors this hour is 0 errors"}`
this one dies on postion 180, can not find what would cause it.

Comment: @Rober try to JSON.stringify the incoming data and console log the result, see if there's anything strange. Also try Object.keys on the data and console.log them.

Comment: @Robert you can loop over the characters and check their ascii codes, see if there's anything weird.

Comment: Nothing really stands out in the stringify.
`{\"eventType\":\"ALERT_TRIGGER\",\n\"title\":\"ALERT TRIGGER: Port Errors\",\n\"text\": \"Alert: Inbound Port Errors for Pulse SSL VPN - New York (MA003VPN01) - ext0 this hour is 0 errors and \nOutbound Port Errors this hour is 0 errors\"}`
Trying to expose Object.keys now.

Comment: So when I try to show the keys, the Object myjson is undefined I presume because it never parses it even with a Stringify of the incoming JSON.

Comment: @Robert I didn't mean the `myjson` after parsing, I meant before. To avoid such confusion, maybe rename the result to `parsedJson` or the incoming data to `incomingJson` or something. Also try the script I put in the answer.

Comment: So when I iterate over the keys of the parsed stringyfied json, I see that every character is being parsed into a key, so I am trying your script now to see if it finds anything.

Comment: I got it working, it was something in the text, I just retyped it and it started working.  Not sure what can got transformed from notepad into the box or it was something the app was transforming, but atleast I know I am not crazy on how to parse.

Thanks for the help